# uninitialized constant Mongoid::Taggable::Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I added [mongoid-taggable](https://github.com/wilkerlucio/mongoid_taggable) to my Gemfile and then added `include Mongoid::Taggable` in my model, but received an error message:

```
uninitialized constant Mongoid::Taggable::Mongo
```

Error trace:

```
app/models/recipe.rb:13:in `include'
app/models/recipe.rb:13:in `<class:Recipe>'
app/models/recipe.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you restart your server? :)

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin Yep, server restarted. I have created tags from scratch just now but still want to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What version of Mongoid are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging too much into the source of Mongoid Taggable, my guess would be that it was built for a 2.x.x version of Mongoid. With the 3.x.x release of Mongoid, the dependency on the `mongo` gem was removed. It doesn't appear that anyone has committed to this gem in over a year, so I doubt that it has any support for a version 3.x.x of Mongoid.

If you are set on using this gem for tagging, you will need to roll back to an earlier release of Mongoid. 2.4.12 was the last stable release in the 2.x.x branch.

Another solution would be to use a different gem. I would recommend [mongoid-tags-arent-hard](http://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid-tags-arent-hard). It is Mongoid 3 compatibile, and works fairly well.

Comment: I've used [this brunch](https://github.com/Florian95/mongoid_taggable) as a plugin to solve it. And thanks for your recommended, it works great! :)

Comment: and sorry I don't have enough reputations to vote your answer up. will come back to vote later. :)